# How to modify this PHP code to print out list of user interests and other arbitrary data?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

If this code prints out the list of user statuses

```
// show statuses
$statuses = $facebook->api(‘/me/statuses’);
foreach($statuses[‘data’] as $status)
{
        echo $status["message"], "<br />";
}
```

How do I modify it so that it prints the interests ? I am thinking-->

```
// show interests
    $interests = $facebook->api(‘/me/interests’);
    foreach($interests[‘???’] as $interest)
    {
            echo $interest["???"], "<br />";

    }
```

I think this is the right idea but i don't know what to put as the arguments for `$interests` and `$interest` and can't find a good reference form FB

Help is appreciated!

Comment: print_r($interests); will show you what the array values are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/me/interests` returns an array of JSON strings, each containing `id`, `name`, `category` and `create_time`

So you'd do it the same way:

```
foreach($interests[‘data’] as $interest)
```

You will then need to simply look at the JSON in `$interest` and extract what you want.

Also note that your app needs the user to grant the `user_interests` and/or `friends_interests` permissions for it to return anything.

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into the Facebook API specifically, you should use `var_dump` or `print_r` to ascertain the structure of the `$interests` variable, then you'll know what to loop.  I would regard such effort as a basic debugging/exploratory practice that you ought to have tried before seeking help.

var_dump docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

print_p docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php

Comment: Thanks...I just thought to do this myself....running a print_r showed the arguments I needed...sorry for posting...PHPnewbie mistake!

Comment: Pah, we all learned somehow.  I, for one, did not sit in any class, but learned by pestering guys who already had it all figured out... or trying a bunch of stuff on my own until I found the way :)